# Google drive not behaving to provided UTI from UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am building an iOS app which uses UIDocumentPickerViewController to open iCloud drive and Google drive. I have provided allowed UTI as 'com.adobe.pdf' as I only need PDF files access. The UTI is working fine in iCloud Drive but google drive provide me access of google sheet files also. Whereas excel files are behaving properly. How can I restrict drive to PDF files only?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using this code :

```
let docActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Document", style: .Default)
    { action -> Void in
        var documentMediaTypes: [String] = []
        documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypePDF))



        let viewController: UIDocumentMenuViewController = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: documentMediaTypes, inMode: .Import)

        viewController.delegate = self
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
          self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })


    }
```

And then check at successful selection of a file

```
 func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    print(url.path)
    if (url.path!.componentsSeparatedByString("/").last!).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last! == "pdf" {
}
}
```

This code

```
var documentMediaTypes: [String] = []
    documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypePDF))
```

makes sure only pdf files are show for picking.

Comment: How to import custom files with extension (Unknown UTI). @hemant3370

Comment: documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypePNG))
          documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypeImage))
            documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypeVideo))
            documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypeMovie))
            documentMediaTypes.append(String(kUTTypeItem))

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need to use custom extensions to import file from cloud storage. and that expansion is not listed in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html

Comment: This is for Export file i need to import from cloud storage with custom extant ion file